# Ignore everything except the bit i created parsers for

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to extract the `setup_requires` and `test_requires` values from the setup.py of a few thousand libraries.  I have this grammer

```
grammar SetupPy ;

file_input: (ignore setupRequires | ignore testRequires )* EOF;

setupRequires :  SETUPDEC '[' dependencyValue* (',' dependencyValue)* ']';
testRequires : TESTDEC '[' dependencyValue* (',' dependencyValue)* ']';
ignore: UNKNOWN_CHAR;
dependencyValue: LISTVAL;

//ignore : UNKNOWN_CHAR? ;

LISTVAL: SHORT_STRING;
SETUPDEC: 'setup_requires' '=';
TESTDEC:  'tests_require' '=';
UNKNOWN_CHAR: . -> channel(HIDDEN);

fragment SHORT_STRING: '\'' ( STRING_ESCAPE_SEQ | ~[\\\r\n\f'] )* '\''
| '"' ( STRING_ESCAPE_SEQ | ~[\\\r\n\f"] )* '"';

fragment STRING_ESCAPE_SEQ
: '\\' .
| '\\'
;
```

which works on a very simple example.  But, when i put it against a full file, the tokens get tripped up on the other things in the file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import with_statement

from setuptools import setup


def get_version(fname='mccabe.py'):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('__version__'):
                return eval(line.split('=')[-1])


def get_long_description():
    descr = []
    for fname in ('README.rst',):
        with open(fname) as f:
            descr.append(f.read())
    return '\n\n'.join(descr)


setup(
    name='mccabe',
    version=get_version(),
    description="McCabe checker, plugin for flake8",
    long_description=get_long_description(),
    keywords='flake8 mccabe',
    author='Tarek Ziade',
    author_email='tarek@ziade.org',
    maintainer='Ian Cordasco',
    maintainer_email='graffatcolmingov@gmail.com',
    url='https://github.com/pycqa/mccabe',
    license='Expat license',
    py_modules=['mccabe'],
    zip_safe=False,
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'flake8.extension': [
            'C90 = mccabe:McCabeChecker',
        ],
    },
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Quality Assurance',
    ],
)
```

How do i setup this grammer to ignore everything except the two values I specified?

Comment: I think you're on the right track with this approach.  I'd be happy to look at it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your earlier question and the ease of parsing the simplified input, in my opinion the quickest approach would be to do simple text preprocessing on these files, discarding all the stuff you don't need and keeping just the two parts you're interested in.
Example:

1. Open each file.
2. Read whole file into string variable.
3. Find start position of token `setup_requires`.
4. From that position, since these are arrays, look for the position of the next occurrence of `]`, which would signal the end of the `setup_requires` array definition.
5. Using those indices, write the complete sentence `setup_requires=['pytest-runner']` to an output file.
6. Follow similar method for token `tests_require`, appending to the output file.
7. Now parse the greatly simplified output file using the grammar I proposed in my [other answer which worked on the simple input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132279/antlr-to-parse-python-setup-file/45133533#45133533).  This way you can avoid parsing all the rest and leverage the provably correct answer I did earlier.
8. Repeat for each input file.

Comment: Well, thats certainly doable.  Ill give it a shot.  so antlr isn't setup as a "search and parse" its really setup to parse the complete file hu.

Comment: @scphantm Yes, it's designed to parse the complete input stream.  So my approach is basically use some simple text processing to provide an input stream for which I've already helped you get the grammar right.  Language is your choice, text processing is easy enough.  You can do it, and quickly, I think!

Comment: I have this thing twitching.  Quick one on the grammer.  With the list value fragment, its returning the quote and double quotes.  how do i modify that to filter those out and just give me the text?

Comment: tinkered with it a bit but wonder, once you have the list tokens, in the listener or visitor why don't you just replace the first and last character ' or " with nothing and be done with it? Easier in time pressure than messing with the grammar.  The way you have SHORT_STRING defined, the quotes are part of the token.  Easy to deal with in your listener or visitor.

Comment: Ok, if thats easier.  i figured this thing would have a lookbehind and lookahead like regex.

Comment: Nope.  Though you could also use a regex to select the patterns you wanted to extract from the big file.  Glad to help; could I trouble you to upvote the answer also so others might find it easier in the future?